# Should Cypress Automation testing be written for local environment or staging?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

When we need to add our Automation scripts to run with GitHub workflows to trigger when we push a commit, for what environment should we write tests?

In the local environment at localhost or for the staging site of the project?

Could anyone please say how it should be written and how can we add Cypress Automation Tests with GitHub CI/CD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let me give this a shot. Of course, I do not know the exact setup of the project that you are working on, but let me give you some pointers, so you can decide for yourself what works best in your setting.

My answer is based on the assumption that you are building an automated regression test set in Cypress with the primary goal to prevent production incidents. In addition, it aims save you tons of 'manual testing' for each release to production because you want to make sure everything is still working properly.

**First of all**, you want your automated tests to run on a stable environment(*). If the environment is not stable, many tests will fail for many reasons, and those are usually not the right ones. You'll spend more time figuring out why your tests are failing, than actually catching issues with it. This makes a local, dev environment not really suited for the task, so I would not pick a localhost environment for this. Especially not when you have multiple developers working in your team, each with their own localhost.

A test environment is already a way more stable environment. You want your tests to only fail when you have an actual issue on your hands. As a rule of thumb, the 'higher' you go, the more stable.

**Second**, you want to catch the issues early in the game, so I would definitely make sure that the tests can run on the environment where all code comes together for the first time (in other words, the environment that has the master branch or whatever your team calls that branch). This is usually the test environment. In my projects, I initially build the set for this environment, and ideally, I run it daily. Your tests won't always pass here (bonus if they do), and that is OK... as long as you understand why they don't ;-)

Some things to keep in mind are integrations or connecting systems, and whether you need those for your tests to pass. In general, you don't want to be (too) dependent on (third-party) integrations for you test cases to go green. Sometimes, when those integrations are vital to the process that you need to test, it is inevitable. However, integrations are often not (fully) set up on test/lower environments. There are workarounds for this, like stubs, but let's not get into that now - that's a whole different topic.

**Third**, you want your tests to run on a production-like environment on the code exactly in the state that it goes to production. This is usually the acceptance, staging or pre-production environment, i.e. the last one before production. These environments often have all integrations in place and are often very similar to production. If you find an issue here, it's almost guaranteed that it is also an issue in production. This is IMO where you want to integrate your tests into your CI/CD pipeline. Ideally, your full automated set is in the pipeline, but in practice, you should only add the tests that are stable and robust, otherwise your production deployments will be blocked very often.

So, ***long story short***, my advice: write your tests for your test environment, where you do your 'manual testing' (I hate that term BTW, all testing is manual... as if there is such a thing as 'manual coding') and run it early and often. Then put the stable ones in the pipeline of the production deployment. If you only have local, staging and production, it should be staging.

If your developers want to run the set on their local environments, they can still do that - you can share the tests with them or even better, they can take it from the repository and run it locally - but I don't think you should make it part of the deployment process always and everywhere. It will slow down your process massively.

You can work with environment variables to easily switch for the environment where you want to run your tests: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Setting

I hope this helps. I'm looking forward to read what others have to say about this, too.

Happy Testing!

Jackie

PS. I see that you also asked about how to add Cypress to your CI/CD pipeline. I think that should be a completely separate topic. It is also way too high level to answer. Maybe it's best to start here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#What-you-ll-learn

(*) I'm talking stable environment here, but this also includes stable code and even a stable application. If your application and code is in a very early stage, really ask yourself whether you already want to start automating your functional UI tests in Cypress - chances are that many things will change (many times) and you'll spend hours updating your tests. Maybe it is better to only think about the scenarios that you want to automate at that stage of the project.

Comment: Thank u so much for your reply.could learn a lot of things from this comment.means a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your automation journey :-)